# Programmatically add a WCF Service Project Item

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte

**Info:** C#, Visual Studio 2010 RC

How can I add a WCF Web Service Project Item to my Project via code?

I can add a Code Class file no problem with:

```
string csItemTemplatePath = soln.GetProjectItemTemplate("CodeFile", "CSharp");

try
{
    projectItems.AddFromTemplate(csItemTemplatePath, fileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // This is just testing, don't shoot me
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

but if I try it with:

```
string itemTemplatePath = soln.GetProjectItemTemplate("WebWcfService", "CSharp");
```

I get an exception that it can't be found

> The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070002)

I got the WebWcfService name from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

I pressume it is something to do with how the Solution looks for it's project items but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Don't ever use ex.Message, unless you're trying to present a "pretty" message to the user. If you want to know what happened, you need to use ex.ToString().

Comment: 1+Thanks for the relevant question

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered for me on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/7f031537-f8c0-4281-bda1-c56cf86b2109

> Hi, Phill
>
> Because WebWcfService is a web
>   project, which is a subtype of CSharp
>   project. So we need to find the
>   WebWcfService this way.

```
string path = soln.GetProjectItemTemplate("WebWcfService.zip", CSharp/Web");
```

> If you have anything unclear, feel
>   free to let me know.
>
> Thanks
>
> Chao